# how to use generics in kotlin as a parameter to the method

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, fragment

In the below code, I want to use generics as parameter in the below posted method. I have a class FragmentLeft and FragmentRight that extends Fragment, and I would like to create a method that accept any them

```
  fun FragmentTransaction.replaceTransaction(layout: Int, fragment : <? : 
  Fragment()>): FragmentTransaction {
    return this.replace(layout, fragment)
  }
```

**code**

```
var fragTransactionInstance = getFragmentManagerInstance()?.let {
        it.getFragmentTransactionInstance()
            ?.replaceTransaction(R.id.fragLeft, 
fragmentLeft)//required:Fragment Found FragmentLeft
            ?.replaceTransaction(R.id.fragRight, 
fragmentRight)//required:Fragment Found FragmentRight
    }?.also {
        it.commit()
    }
```

Comment: Unless those fragments extend from a common superclass you can't do it without declaring multiple methods or using unsafe casts.

Comment: @Pawel please see the code section i added above..it includes the error rreceived – Amr just now    Edit    Delete

Comment: What are `getFragmentManagerInstance` and `getFragmentTransactionInstance`?